# three.js - bufferGeometry not showing

Tags: vue.js, three.js

it's my first question, for my first project with three.js, i hope it's not too simple, i already researched but with no success.
So i'm creating a Line2 because i need to control the fatness, so i followed this example (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat) and it was working.

But then i saw that i also need to update the points of my geometry, so made some modifications following this example: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

And now my mesh it's not showing anymore, here is a relevant code, i'm inside a vue component, so it has some different syntax.

```
//mounted()
this.arcGeometry1 = new LineGeometry()
// set maximum size for buffer of LineGeometry,
var positions = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
this.arcGeometry1.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) ); //  the number of values of the array, not drawRange
this.matLine2 = new LineMaterial({
color: 0x000000,
linewidth: 3,
dashed: false
});
this.matLine2.resolution.set(( this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight ))
this.arcMesh = new Line2(this.arcGeometry1, this.matLine2 );
update()
init()


//update()
var positions = this.arcMesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  for (let x = 0; x < arcPath.length; x++) {
    positions[x] = arcPath[x]
  }

  this.arcMesh.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, arcPath.length );
  this.arcMesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
  //this.arcMesh.computeLineDistances();
  this.earthArcMesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

//init()
this.scene.add(this.arcMesh);

//render()
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
this.arcMesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
this.arcMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

Since i implemented bufferGeometry the mesh is not showing in the render, but when i debug it, seems fine because the geometry points are correctly loaded

```
Line2 {…}
castShadow: (...)
children: (...)
frustumCulled: (...)
geometry: LineGeometry
    attributes: Object
        position: BufferAttribute
            array: Float32Array(135)
                [0 … 99]
                0: -148.2235870361328
                1: -17.804668426513672
                2: 0.0008591873338446021
                3: -147.93746948242188
                4: -20.358715057373047
                5: 0.0009825639426708221
                6: -147.60552978515625
                7: -22.92180633544922
                8: 0.0011064092395827174
                9: -147.22335815429688
                10: -25.517356872558594
                11: 0.0012318536173552275
                ...

boundingSphere: Sphere
    center: Vector3
    radius: 0
```

A hint may be that always in the console debugging i see that the bounding sphere has radius 0? Even if did compute it in the snippet before. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by using `line.geometry.maxInstancedCount = N`

insted of `line.geometry.setDrawRange(N)`

Because "BufferGeometry.setDrawRange() can’t be used with wide lines since it internally uses instanced rendering. " 
You can see the thread: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/fat-lines-setting-geometry-data-does-not-work/14448/8
I think that also the answers here would have worked, I just couldn't, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering "fat lines" using `LineGeometry` from the three.js examples, and you want to be able to modify a vertex position.

To `LineGeometry.prototype` add the method:

```
setPositionAt: function ( index, x, y, z ) {

    this.attributes.instanceStart.setXYZ( index, x, y, z );

    if ( index > 0 ) this.attributes.instanceEnd.setXYZ( index - 1, x, y, z );

    return this;

},
```

To use it:

```
line.geometry.setPositionAt( i, x, y, z ); // updates the coords of the i-th point
```

If you need to change the number of points in the line, the best way is to allocate a buffer sufficient to hold your longest line, and then control the number of line segments rendered be setting:

```
line.geometry.maxInstancedCount = N; // this will render N line segments (N + 1 points)
```

three.js r.115

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm trying to go down this road, but it now gives me the error ` "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setXYZ' of undefined" `

Comment: I also tried to change the setAttribute argument from THREE.BufferAttribute to:
 `this.arcGeometry1.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) ); `
but it still gives me the error

Comment: Copy how the three.js fat line example instantiates the geometry: `var geometry = new LineGeometry(); geometry.setPositions( positions );`

Comment: It still gives me the same mistake ` "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setXYZ' of undefined" `, I don't know if it's because I'm not adding the method correctly inside vue.
Do you know an example where they render a fat line and modify their vertex positions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in latest Instance buffer class of threejs, use:

`line.geometry.instanceCount = N`  instead of `line.geometry.maxInstancedCount = N`